# Highchart yAxis opposite is not working in type datetime

Tags: php, yii, highcharts

I have followed the documentation of highcharts according to the documentation if we want axis on the both end we have to do.

```
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'primary'
            }
        },
        {
            opposite : true,
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'secondary'
            }
        },
    ],
```

But in my case I am getting primary axis as expected but secondary axis is not giving desired result. It shows the text "secondary" but not giving the axis.

Comment: Have you assigned series to second axis? Other option will be to set linkedTo option for second axis, so it will copy ticks from the first one. Wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/up9Lebps/ , Right: http://jsfiddle.net/up9Lebps/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/up9Lebps/2/

Comment: thanks http://jsfiddle.net/up9Lebps/2/ was usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen in case no visible series has axis assigned or axis has no `linkedTo` property set to a visible axis.

To fix it you can:

If you just want to show 2 axes for one series - set linkedTo for yAxis.
API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.linkedTo

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/up9Lebps/2/

If you want to show 2 axes for different series - set yAxis for series.
API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.yAxis

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/up9Lebps/3/